# Error creating Magento API method - getAllowedAttributes

Tags: php, web-services, api, magento

I'm creating a module that adds a method to the magento API sopa_v1​​: api.xml within my "etc" is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <obterenderecosfiltrado_api translate="title" module="obterenderecosfiltrado">
                <title>Myapi</title>
                <acl>obterenderecosfiltrado/api</acl>
                <model>obterenderecosfiltrado/api</model>
                <methods>                    
                        <getaddressbyfilter translate="title" module="obterenderecosfiltrado">
                            <title>Obter Address Filtrado</title>
                            <acl>obterenderecosfiltrado/getaddressbyfilter</acl>
                        </getaddressbyfilter>
                </methods>
            </obterenderecosfiltrado_api>
        </resources>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <obterenderecosfiltrado translate="title" module="obterenderecosfiltrado">
                    <title>ObterEnderecosFiltrado</title>
                    <sort_order>2000</sort_order>                    
                    <getaddressbyfilter translate="title" module="obterenderecosfiltrado">
                        <title>Obter Address Filtrado</title>
                    </getaddressbyfilter>
                </obterenderecosfiltrado>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

and my Api.php within "model":

```
<?php
class Novapc_ObterEnderecosFiltrado_Model_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{        

        protected $_mapAttributes = array(
            'customer_address_id' => 'entity_id'
        );

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->_ignoredAttributeCodes[] = 'parent_id';
        }

        public function getaddressbyfilter($filters)
        {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        if (is_array($filters)) {
            try {
                foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
                    if (isset($this->_mapAttributes[$field])) {
                        $field = $this->_mapAttributes[$field];
                    }

                    $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        $result = array();
        foreach ($collection as $address) {
            $data = $address->toArray();
            $row  = array();

            foreach ($this->_mapAttributes as $attributeAlias => $attributeCode) {
                $row[$attributeAlias] = (isset($data[$attributeCode]) ? $data[$attributeCode] : null);
            }

            foreach ($this->getAllowedAttributes($address) as $attributeCode => $attribute) {
                if (isset($data[$attributeCode])) {
                    $row[$attributeCode] = $data[$attributeCode];
                }
            }

            $customerId = $address->getParentId();

            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

            $row['customer_id'] = $customerId;
            $row['is_default_billing'] = $customer->getDefaultBilling() == $address->getId();
            $row['is_default_shipping'] = $customer->getDefaultShipping() == $address->getId();

            $result[] = $row;
        }

        return $result;
        }
}
```

O Erro esta na TAG:

```
  foreach ($this->getAllowedAttributes($address) as $attributeCode => $attribute) {
     if (isset($data[$attributeCode])) {
        $row[$attributeCode] = $data[$attributeCode];
     }
  }
```

me retorna o seguinte:

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to undefined method Novapc_ObterEnderecosFiltrado_Model_Api::getAllowedAttributes() in C:\wamp\www\conectar_ws.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\conectar_ws.php(13): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\conectar_ws.php(13): SoapClient->call('739882c5e4d2184...', 'obterenderecosf...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\conectar_ws.php on line 13
```

Comment: I think it's quite clear. Neither your class Novapc_ObterEnderecosFiltrado_Model_Api and Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract (which it is extended from) do not have the method getAllowedAttributes(). Create it and should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what the error means that there is no method `getAllowedAttributes` neither in Novapc_ObterEnderecosFiltrado_Model_Api nor in class that it extends - Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract

So you need to implement this method in your class

Comment: Could tell me how I implement this method in my class? I'm getting this code from another programmer, I'm a little lost.

Comment: Sorry, I managed to solve, I just extended my class to "Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Api"